# React does not render component but console.log works perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a component based on the navigation. `console.log()` has no issues but it doesn't show anything if I try to render a component.

```
import Header from "../components/header";

const navigation = [
  { name: "Chat", href: "#", current: true },
  { name: "Coffee", href: "#", current: false },
  { name: "Gifts", href: "#", current: false },
];

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.values(navigation).forEach((element) => {
        if (element.current === true) {
          switch (element.name) {
            case "Chat":
              console.log("Works");
              return <Header />;
            case "Coffee":
              return <Header />;
            case "Gifts":
              return <Header />;
            default: {
              console.log("Wrong");
            }
          }
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything (well, it returns undefined). Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

Comment: Yes, oh my god, I just cannot believe I did that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `map` instead of `forEach` because `forEach` does not return anything. Thank you [@evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox).